# Generate a multi scatter subplot - unexpected results returned

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot, scatter

I am new to python and I am trying to create a subplot of multiple months.  What happens is that the block of 3 x3 is generated but is empty, then each chart follows underneath one another which doesn't allow for easy viewing.

Here is my code which I've lifted from a similar question.

```
def scat_months2(df,prod):
    """Print scatter for all months as sub plots of any given product"""
    uniq=sorted(set(train2.YM))[0:9]
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 3, figsize=(6, 4), sharex=True, sharey=True)
    for period in uniq:
        df[(df["YM"]==period) & (df["item_id"]==prod)].plot(x='shop_id',
            y='item_price',
            kind='scatter',
            label=period,alpha=0.2)

    fig.tight_layout()
```

I have tried to generate some random data for so you can help me, but this also hasn't worked out as I'd hoped (again python newbie)... it generates a different error.  I hope this still allows you can easily fix my example and then see the same result I see..

If you tell me how I could generate my random data properly too, that would really help my learning.
I apologise for not being able to come with a functional example.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

T=pd.Series([201301,201301,201301,201301,201301,201301,201301,201301,201301])
Shop=pd.Series([1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3])
Price=pd.Series(np.random.randint(10, size=(9)))
ds1=pd.DataFrame(dict(T = T, Shop=Shop,Price = Price))
T2=pd.Series([201302,201302,201302,201302,201302,201302,201302,201302,201302])
ds2=pd.DataFrame(dict(T = T2, Shop=Shop,Price = Price))
T3=pd.Series([201303,201303,201303,201303,201303,201303,201303,201303,201303])
ds3=pd.DataFrame(dict(T = T3, Shop=Shop,Price = Price))
ds=pd.concat([ds1,ds2,ds3], axis=0)
ds.index=range(27)

def scat_months2(df):
    """Print scatter for all months as sub plots of any given product"""
    uniq=sorted(set(df.T))
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 1, figsize=(6, 4), sharex=True, sharey=True)
    for period in uniq:
        df[df["T"]==period].plot(x='Shop',
            y='Price',
            kind='scatter')

    fig.tight_layout()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the `ax` parameter of the plot function:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

T=pd.Series([201301,201301,201301,201301,201301,201301,201301,201301,201301])
Shop=pd.Series([1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3])
Price=pd.Series(np.random.randint(10, size=(9)))
ds1=pd.DataFrame(dict(T = T, Shop=Shop,Price = Price))
T2=pd.Series([201302,201302,201302,201302,201302,201302,201302,201302,201302])
ds2=pd.DataFrame(dict(T = T2, Shop=Shop,Price = Price))
T3=pd.Series([201303,201303,201303,201303,201303,201303,201303,201303,201303])
ds3=pd.DataFrame(dict(T = T3, Shop=Shop,Price = Price))
ds=pd.concat([ds1,ds2,ds3], axis=0)
ds.index=range(27)

def scat_months2(df):
    """Print scatter for all months as sub plots of any given product"""
    uniq=sorted(set(df['T']))
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(len(uniq), 1, figsize=(6, 4), sharex=True, sharey=True)
    for i, period in enumerate(uniq):
        df[df["T"]==period].plot(x='Shop',
            y='Price',
            kind='scatter',
            ax=axes[i])

    fig.tight_layout()
    plt.show()

scat_months2(ds)
```

[image]

(There was a small error in your example that I corrected to make it work: df.T returns the transposed dataframe, if your column name is T then you need to explicitly write `df['T']` instead of `df.T`)

---

**PS:** In order to conveniently **create sample data** you can use numpy's [repeat](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) and [tile](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) functions:

```
months = [201301, 201302, 201303]
shops = [1,2,3]
n = 3
df = pd.DataFrame({'Month': np.repeat(months, n*len(shops)), 'Shop': np.tile(shops, n*len(months)), 'Price': np.random.randint(10, size=n*len(shops)*len(months))})
```

Comment: Thank you.  I ran this on my actual data set and it fails when I add the labels or set alpha as per the first piece of code.  The error is AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_figure'.  However, when I run your code, it works... I will try to figure out where the difference is and replicate the example now you've shown me how to create the data more easily

Comment: This is because your plot grid it 2D (3x3), use `ax=axes.flatten()[i]` in this case.

Comment: This has worked.  I don't really understand why but ok... I actually wanted to print 36 months of data this way.  When I tried to change the dimensions to "fig, axes = plt.subplots(12, 3, figsize=(6, 4), sharex=True, sharey=True)", the result is illegible.  Can you advise why?  Thanks for this.

Comment: without flattening the 2D axes array, axes[i] will return an array of axis objects and this array hat not attribute `get_figure`. What you need is a single axis object, e.g. `axes[i][j]` but as we don't have the second index `j`, we first flatten the 2D array into a 1D array.